# How to configure Jackson for Pact Test in Spring Boot Test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, pact

I am trying to create Pact Test, my `provider` responds with incorrect data for `consumer`.
For example it responds with incorrect date format.
Consumer pact expectation: .datetime("created-at", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
Provider responds with: timestamp long value.
Real API responds with: "2023-03-30T10:22:32.975+00:00" for example.

Provider test:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "xxx"
})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Provider("MyService")
@PactBroker
public class PactTest extends IntegrationBase {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup(PactVerificationContext context) {
        context.setTarget(new HttpTestTarget("localhost", port));
    }

    @TestTemplate
    @ExtendWith(PactVerificationSpringProvider.class)
    void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context) {
        context.verifyInteraction();
    }

@State(value = "GET ALL DATA", action = StateChangeAction.SETUP)
    void getAll() {
         //some code
        repository.save(entity);
    }
```

How should I configure my provider test to respond with jackson configuration I have in project?

Comment: The issue here seems to be that the consumer is expecting the wrong value, and the provider actually provides a differently formatted timestamp? Aren't you best updating the consumer test?

Comment: Well, consumer expects data same as in real service. Of course I can adjust consumer to make fields matching, but it is a cheat :) I need to test correct data, so in my case provider  provides incorrect data and doesnt match with consumer. @MatthewFellows